# Применение случайных стилей при выводе в цикле через php

Tags: php, javascript, css

Вывожу статьи в цикле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу, чтобы у каждого элемента было случайное свойство css `transform: rotate()` от -2 до +2 deg, подскажите, как такое можно реализовать?

Вот код вывода статей:

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
                        <div class="article">
                                <div class="article_title"><?php echo $article['title']; ?></div>
                                <div class="article_img">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $article['img1']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <a href=page_show_ads.php?id_ads=<?php 
    echo $article["article_id"];
?>
                                 class="article_more">Подробнее</a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При построении html документа, через php в атрибуте style зарандомить от `-2` до `2`

```
<div class='article' style='transform: rotate(<?php echo rand(-2, 2); ?>deg)'></div>
```

Comment: Только не фото а сам блок

Comment: Спасибо, так просто, я что то не сообразил, лошок)

Comment: @идентикон Пожалуйста, ставьте отметку напротив правильных ответов

Comment: @идентикон, думаю такое у многих бывает)

Comment: @doofy Конечно)